# Remove app from 'Recently Used' list in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, info.plist

I would like to know whether there is any plist property/way to remove the app from the recently used list i.e., when you double-tap on home button.

Due to iOS 7's new look and feel, I ask this question for security reasons in the application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control that the app appears, that's managed by the OS.

You can detect when the app is going to be backgrounded and hide the information you don't want to be visible.

From Apple:

> Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the
>   background: When an app transitions to the background, the system
>   takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents
>   briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before
>   returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should
>   hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information
>   that might be captured as part of the snapshot.

Use `applicationDidEnterBackground` to detect when the app is going to be backgrounded

Comment: Thanks :) Will add a masking window or execute any other such alternative. Appreciate the fast reply.

Comment: Quick question - Can we access these app snapshots programmatically?

Comment: Im not sure but I dont think so